# Match elements before and after some criteria

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Suppose I have an **ordered** (by `$sort` aggregation pipeline stage) list of documents:

```json
    { x: 0 }
    { x: 1 }
    { x: 3 }
    { x: 4 }
    { x: 5 }
    { x: 6 }
```

Now I can select all documents where `x >= 3` using the aggregation pipeline stage:

```js
    { $match: { x: { $gte: 3 } } }
```

But is it also possible to match all documents where `x >= 3` AND the first element before the first matched element in a **single** query?

The expected result is:

```json
    { x: 1 }
    { x: 3 }
    { x: 4 }
    { x: 5 }
    { x: 6 }
```

(I need this for relay compliant pagination)

Comment: the expected result should be 0,3,4,5,6?

Comment: No. The first matched item is `{ x: 3 }`. The item before that is `{ x: 1 }`. Edit: you are right, I was missing a word in my initial question which totally changes the problem. I will fix that now, thanks! <3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `$facet` to separate into 2 pipelines for processing. Then use `$setUnion` to regroup the result back.

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$facet": {
      "smaller": [
        {
          "$match": {
            x: {
              $lt: 3
            }
          }
        },
        {
          $sort: {
            x: -1
          }
        },
        {
          "$limit": 1
        }
      ],
      "larger": [
        {
          "$match": {
            x: {
              $gte: 3
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  // cosmetics to revert back to original form
  {
    "$project": {
      final: {
        "$setUnion": [
          "$smaller",
          "$larger"
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$unwind": "$final"
  },
  {
    "$replaceRoot": {
      "newRoot": "$final"
    }
  }
])
```

Here is the [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/iaKBfVDGeiV) for your reference.

Comment: You are my hero. <3